# Apply Bug Fix to Open CV library

Tags: c++, opencv, adtf

I am currently preparing a work project utilizing ADTF 2.9.0, OpenCV 2.4.3 (March 2016) and Visual Studio 2010 under Win7 x64.

Unfortunately, I came across [THIS](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7204) bug. It results in an ADTF crash when I apply cornerSubPix() on a video frame with some bad gradients.
I know the bug has been fixed on Sept 2016 but I don't know how to implement the fix in my current installation since I cannot update to a newer OpenCV version.

I already tried replacing the imgproc lib with an updated one. But after compiling, ADTF seems to have problems finding the lib or some dll files.

My last Idea would be to download the source from 2.4.3 and fix the bug in the cornerSubPix.cpp and recompile it then.
But I can't find the source files for that specific version.

Are there any other ideas of how to solve this problem?

Comment: The source is here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Both the source for [2.4.3](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/2.4.3) as well as the [bugfix](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7206/commits/a6e5ebafcf1ba5fa4b27f23b0581dee917e3198c) are available in the git history.

You will either need to checkout 2.4.3 and apply the patch yourself, or checkout a newer tag (looks like the bugfix is available starting with 2.4.13.1) and build from that.

Though building from source will almost certainly be harder than just upgrading OpenCV.  (Again, just an upgrade to 2.4.13.1 should be sufficient; you don't need to update to the latest version if you are worried about API changes.)